# Previous and next records using onclick button in a Details View in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I need to move through a records using onclick button  in a details view.  The problem is that my PK is a varchar and is a little bit complicated for me to do that. I need to cut the part that is a sequential number to move to a previous and next record in C#.  For example my PK is  MD1234-289-1-0000, the sequential number is 289 and I need to move through a records using this part of the PK.  I declared in sql this query and works but I don't know how to add this query in C# or what is the correct way to do that.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(21) = 'MD1234-289-1-0000'
DECLARE @start_index INT
DECLARE @end_index INT

SELECT @start_index = CHARINDEX('-', @text, 1)

SELECT @end_index = CHARINDEX('-', @text, CHARINDEX('-', @text, 1) + 1)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@text, @start_index + 1, @end_index - @start_index - 1)
```

Any example or idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Will it always be AA####-###-#-#### ?

Comment: Yes,  always is the same structure. The only part that change it is AA####-289-#-#### because is a sequencial number. I need to use this part to move to previous and next records with a onclick button for a details view.  Thanks!!